# how to factorize $ 4a^3b-9ab$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

how can I factorize $4a^3b-9ab$ ?

it's not in the shape of any common factorization formula like $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab$ or ...

so it must be factorized indirectly (maybe by adding and subtracting some monomials).

anyhow I don't have any idea to do it. who can help?

Comment: Notice that $4a^3b=4a^2ab$

Comment: First factor out $ab$.

Comment: yes @Uzman. got it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$4a^3b-9ab=a(4a^2b-9b)=ab(4a^2-9)=ab(2a+3)(2a-3)$$